# Scala Lift - SBT compilation error (Sources not found)

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I have my lift project working perfectly on my local windows machine, and am now attempting to put it live on our RHEL5 server.

The project is in

```
ROOT/lift24
```

When I attempt to run

```
./sbt update ~jetty-run
```

in the lift24 folder I get the following after successful update:

```
[info] Compiling main sources...
[error] source file '/lift24/src/main/scala/code/api/UserAPI.scala;src/main/scala
/code/snippet/RoomDataSnippet.scala;src/main/scala/code/comet/UserServer.scala;
src/main/scala/code/comet/StreamServer.scala;src/main/scala/code/rogue
/QueryField.scala;src/main/scala/code/snippet/StreamSnippet.scala;src/main/scala
/code/comet/PresentationServer.scala;src/main/scala/code/comet
/PresentationComet.scala;src/main/scala/code/snippet/RoomCometSnippet.scala;src
/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala;src/main/scala/code/comet/ChatComet.scala;src
/main/scala/code/api/RoomAPI.scala;src/main/scala/code/snippet/UserSnippet.scala;src
/main/scala/code/comet/ChatServer.scala;src/main/scala/code/comet/StreamComet.scala;src
/main/scala/code/comet/UserComet.scala;src/main/scala/code/snippet
/ChatSnippet.scala;src/main/scala/code/snippet/PresentationSnippet.scala' 
could not be found
```

All of the files are in

```
ROOT/lift24/src
```

It seems this is a path issue, but do not know how to tell sbt where to look.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Your files should be in src/main/scala not src

Comment: Hi, thanks they are, I needed to do a clean build to fix the issue :)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer

Comment: You should also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, just run:

```
sbt -clean
```

:)